# Error with old code TYPE=HEAP for temporary table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an old code that was working:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tree (id INTEGER, parent_id INTEGER) type=HEAP;
```

Now I have mysql 5 and this code is not working.
What is the proper way to create temporary table in the memory? 
I have searched into [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

but cannot find proper example.

Comment: Change TYPE clause: type=HEAP => ENGINE=HEAP, [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type is deprecated in new versions. Check the version of mysql and use `Engine = Memory.`

Comment: I have to read again what is the difference bethween ENGINE=MEMORY and ENGINE=HEAP.

Comment: @user1408669 `MEMORY` and `HEAP` are synonyms to `ENGINE` names in MySQL. [Read here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).