# Mysql restore db syntax error in procedure

Tags: mysql

Here's the situation: I dumped structure of my db on one machine a tried to restore it second one. But in the process of restoring db error occurres and i have no idea what's wrong with that part of sql code.

Here's the mysql error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5846: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=HEAP;
     WHILE TRUE DO
        SET _paramList = TRIM(_paramList);
       ' at line 13
```

Need to add, i dumped the db structure on mysql 5.1.59 and trying to restore on 5.5.30.

I've already tried compatible option in mysql dump and restore, searched internet with no success.

**EDIT:**

here's the whole procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 PROCEDURE `ws_core_parameters`(IN is_proc_name CHAR(64), IN is_db_name CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    DECLARE _paramList VARCHAR(800);
    DECLARE _parameter VARCHAR(100);
    SELECT
        CAST(a.param_list AS CHAR(800))
    INTO
        _paramList
    FROM mysql.proc a
    WHERE a.name = is_proc_name
        AND a.db = is_db_name
    LIMIT 1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE system_proc.__parameters ( s_parameter VARCHAR(20) ) TYPE=HEAP;
    label: WHILE TRUE DO
        SET _paramList = TRIM(_paramList);
        IF(COALESCE(_paramList, '') = '') THEN
            LEAVE label;
        END IF;
        SET _parameter = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_paramList, ',', 1);
        SET _paramList = SUBSTR(_paramList, LENGTH(_parameter)+2);
        INSERT INTO system_proc.__parameters (s_parameter)
            VALUES (
                TRIM(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                        SUBSTR(_parameter,
                            LENGTH(
                                SUBSTRING_INDEX(_parameter, ' ', 1))+2), ' ', 1)));
    END WHILE label;
    SELECT
        SUBSTR(s_parameter, 1-(
            LENGTH(s_parameter))) AS s_parameter
    FROM system_proc.__parameters WHERE s_parameter != '';
    DROP TABLE system_proc.__parameters;
END */;;
```

Comment: Please post your procedure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change TYPE=HEAP to either, ENGINE=HEAP or ENGINE=MEMORY

Links for reference:

[TYPE=HEAP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829392/error-with-old-code-type-heap-for-temporary-table-in-mysql)

[MYSQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)